# use different sql query for toggle button

Tags: android, sql

I'm searching for user input in a database. It is a dictionary app. I have a toggle button that allows user to switch between 2 languages. It works, however it doesn't work when I switch to a different language. Basically I want to apply a different sql query to when the button is switched to another language.

Here is my code:

```
try {

        Cursor cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fr_definition JOIN fr_adresse_definition ON fr_definition.data_id = fr_adresse_definition.definition WHERE index_nom_adresse='"+word[0].toLowerCase().trim()+"'", null);

        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {

            if (word[1] == null || word[1].equals("English")) {
                translatedWord = cursor.getString(2);
            } else {

                 //dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM en_definition JOIN en_adresse_definition ON en_definition.data_id = en_adresse_definition.definition WHERE index_nom_adresse='"+word[0].toLowerCase().trim()+"'", null);
                translatedWord = cursor.getString(1);
            }
        } else {
            translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
        }
        cursor.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException sqle) {
        translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
    }

    dictionary.close();
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking here. What is not working?  Do you want the code that is commented out to work, but it doesn't?  Do you want to use a different query if you are not in English?

Comment: Yes, when toggle button is pressed I want to use a different query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this let you use your other query?

```
try {
    Cursor cursor;

    if (word[1] == null || word[1].equals("English")) {
         cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM fr_definition JOIN fr_adresse_definition ON fr_definition.data_id = fr_adresse_definition.definition WHERE index_nom_adresse='"+word[0].toLowerCase().trim()+"'", null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
             translatedWord = cursor.getString(2);
         }
    } else {
         cursor = dictionary.getDictionaryDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM en_definition JOIN en_adresse_definition ON en_definition.data_id = en_adresse_definition.definition WHERE index_nom_adresse='"+word[0].toLowerCase().trim()+"'", null);
         cursor.moveToFirst();
         if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
              translatedWord = cursor.getString(1);
         } 
    }

    cursor.close();
} catch (SQLiteException sqle) {
    translatedWord = "The word is not in database";
}

dictionary.close();
```